# ¿Se puede saber que thread termina primero?

Tags: java, hilos

estoy haciendo un pequeño ejercicio en Java para conocer más el funcionamiento de los `Threads` y quiero saber qué hilo termina primero.

Mi código es el siguiente, trate de hacerlo con banderas e incluso he usado el método getState pero no logro saber cual termina primero, para que la impresión de la pantalla sea "T o L (dependiendo el caso) ha terminado primero

```
public class Threads {

private static int i=0;
private static int j=0;
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){@Override public void run(){to();}});
    Thread l = new Thread(new Runnable(){@Override public void run(){li();}});

    t.start();
    l.start();

}

public static void to(){
    try{
        for(i = 0;i<=20;i++){
            System.out.print("T"+" ");
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if(i==20 && j<=20){
                System.out.println("La t ha terminado");
            }
        }

        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
}

public static void li(){
    try{
        for(j = 0;j<=20;j++){
            System.out.print("L" + " ");
            Thread.sleep(50);
            if(j==15) {
                System.out.print(" La l se quedo dormida ");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

            if(j==15) System.out.print(" la l desperto ");

            if(j==20 && i<=20){
                System.out.println("La l ha terminado");
            }
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
```

}

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Tienes que comprobar es si el hilo **sigue** vivo. Tienes el método java.lang.Thread.isAlive(), más en el siguiente enlace: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_isalive.htm

Comment: Me parece que lo más fácil es que, al final de cada hilo, pongas un `system.out.println("nombreHilo terminado")`

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el objetivo? En general, de un *thread* no te interesa exactamente cuando acaba sino cuanda acaba la ejecución de tu lógica, y para eso lo que comenta @Aritzbn (o activar un flag en el thread principal) parece suficiente. Pero esa solución no te da exactamente cuando acaba el *thread* (un *thread* podría imprimir el mensaje pero entonces ser reemplazado por el otro *thread* que podría imprimir el mensaje en segunda posición y entonces acabar antes que el primer thread).

Comment: Muchas gracias, @s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes usar una variable con la que sepas si alguno terminó:

```
private boolean alguienTermino = false;

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override public void run(){
        to();
        termino("T");
    }});

Thread l = new Thread(new Runnable()
     {@Override public void run(){
        li();
        termino("L")
     }});

public synchronized void termino(String quienTermino) {
    if (alguienTermino) {
      System.out.println(quienTermino+" terminó después");
    }
    else {
      alguienTermino = true;
      System.out.println(quienTermino+" terminó primero");
    }
}
```